# Parse URL to get thumbnail image of the video or website using jQuery and JSF

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jquery-plugins, jsf-2

I am building a social application which needs to include context relevant to certain information as this makes things a lot nicer for the user, like in Facebook an Google+. Is there a jQuery plugin or JSF plugin that can make a screenshot of the website or video?

I am also working on the coding using jQuery as below, and it is not complete.

### jQuery

```
var content = $("#wall").val();
URL objUrl = new URL(content);
InputStream is = objUrl.openStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory bdf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
```

### XHTML Page

```
<ui:composition>
  <h:form>
    <input name="current_img" id="current_img" type="hidden" />
    <input name="ajax_flag" id="ajax_flag" type="hidden" />
  </h:form>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div style="border: solid 1px #B4BBCD;">
      <div id="fetched_data">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div id="ajax_content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="textareaWrap">
      <textarea id="wall"></textarea>
      <div id="sharebtn">
        <a class="button Share" style="" id="shareButton">Share</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ui:composition>
```